# SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound -- SQL error using java to query database JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String pubBooks = "select title_name " +
                "from publisher, title " +
                "where pub_name = ? " +
                "and publisher.pub_no = title.pub_no " +
                "order by title_name";
        ResultSet rS = stmt.executeQuery(pubBooks);
        stmt.close();
        String pubss = "Irwin";
        PreparedStatement pStmt = 
            con.prepareStatement(pubBooks);
        pStmt.setString(1, pubss);
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Hey, I'm trying to use JDBC to query my database to the the list of book titles produced by that publisher however I run into the error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound.  I've been trying everything that I can think of but I am just not quite sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with trying `PreparedStatement`, except that you just called the wrong "execute" method.  Use the [`executeQuery()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) to return your `ResultSet`.

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = 
con.prepareStatement(pubBooks);
pStmt.setString(1, pubss);
ResultSet rS = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: You don't need your `Statement` at all, just your `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

Statement can't be used when supplying parameters to the query, use PreparedStatement. You may have to revise your code as below:

```
    String pubBooks = "select title_name " +
            "from publisher, title " +
            "where pub_name = ? " +
            "and publisher.pub_no = title.pub_no " +
            "order by title_name";

    String pubss = "Irwin";

    PreparedStatement pStmt =  con.prepareStatement(pubBooks);
    pStmt.setString(1, pubss);
    ResultSet rS = pStmt.executeQuery();

    //TODO: code to use resultset rS

    rS.close();
    pstmt.close();
```